# fct_reorder/ggplot2 not ordering as desired

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse

I am working on the most recent TidyTuesday data and had an issue in my plot. New Jersey is shown above Nashville despite Nashville overall has more values. I am unsure how to fix this.

I think it has something to do with the one tweet by user etmckinley being sorted in Nashville first since it alphabetically comes before username sqlsekou. Perhaps there is a way to reverse the sorting and have it work correctly?

If not, how else can I order the data correctly to have Nashville above New Jersey?

```
library(tidyverse)
tweets <- readr::read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rfordatascience/tidytuesday/master/data/2021/2021-06-15/tweets.csv')

top_states <- tweets %>% 
  filter(
    location != "iPhone: 34.704040,-86.722909",
    location != "Kevin.Elder@GCSU.edu"
  ) %>% 
  drop_na(location) %>% 
  count(location, sort = TRUE) %>% 
  slice_max(n, n = 7) %>% 
  pull(location)

tweets %>% 
  filter(
    location != "iPhone: 34.704040,-86.722909",
    location != "Kevin.Elder@GCSU.edu"
  ) %>% 
  drop_na(location) %>% 
  count(location, username, sort = TRUE) %>% 
  filter(location %in% top_states) %>% 
  mutate(location = fct_reorder(location, n)) %>% 
  mutate(username = fct_reorder(username, -n)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(n, location, fill = username)) +
    geom_col() +
    scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set3") +
    labs(
      x = "Quantity of tweets",
      y = "Location",
      title = "Tweets by location over 3 month period",
      subtitle = "Filled by username"
    )
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, `fct_reorder` reorders by the median value. Your Nashville bar has 2 components, one big, one small, and the median is half way inbetween. Your NJ bar has only one component, so the median is the full value. Override the default in `fct_reorder` by setting `.fun = sum`. See `?fct_reorder` for more details.